# permission denied for schema public on popSQL

Tags: sql

```
CREATE TABLE student
(
    fname VARCHAR(20),
    lname VARCHAR(20),
    Adresse VARCHAR(14)
);
```

Comment: PopSQL is jut a SQL client that can connect to different database products. The answer will depend on which DBMS product you are using (Postgres, Oracle, SQL Server, ....)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The user has to be granted the permission. Below is my practice, try and see whether it will work.

1. Move to the "Manage Connection"

[image]

2. Change the permission of the user you are using from "can use" to "can edit"

[image]